# How to add new object/ type and type to existing Collection

Tags: excel, class, vba, object, collections

I have two questions.

1. I would like to add a new object type (not sure which) in a new sub to an existing collection which is made in underlying sub. So in an other sub I would like to add psecs.pNom to this collection (securities).
2. I would like to add more rows (secId) to this existing collection (securities). Again in an other sub.

How to do this?

Thanks, Amir

```
Sub testclass()

rijaantal_LenDump = Application.CountA(Sheets("Len_Dump").Range("A:A"))
kolomaantal_LenDump = Application.CountA(Sheets("Len_Dump").Range("1:1"))

Sheets("Len_Dump").Select
positions = Sheets("Len_Dump").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(rijaantal_LenDump, kolomaantal_LenDump))

kolomSecID = 8


Set securities = New Collection

For i = 1 To rijaantal_LenDump
Set psecs = New CMpos
psecs.secId = CStr(positions(i, 8))
psecs.L4 = CStr(positions(i, 4))
If Not Exists(securities, psecs.secId) Then securities.Add psecs, psecs.secId
Next i

Debug.Print securities.Count

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the collection ByRef to the other procedure.

```
Public Sub AddAnotherObject(ByRef colSecurities As Collection)

    Dim objOther As SomeOtherObject

    Set objOther = New SomeOtherObject

    colSecurities.Add objOther, CStr(objOther.ID)

End Sub
```

When you get back to the calling procedure, the collection's count will be one higher and the object will be in the collection.  The opposite of ByRef is ByVal. Changes to a variable passed ByVal are lost once the procedure ends.